# PhpMyAdmin 4.7.6 Won't Export Data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Trying to export (backup) a database

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Class
> 'PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Components\SetOperation' not found in
> /home/dmitrych/public_html/dbadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/src/Statement.php:386
> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /home/dmitrych/public_html/dbadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/src/Statement.php(90):
>
> PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Statement->parse(Object(PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Parser),
> Object(PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\TokensList))
>
> ## 1 /home/dmitrych/public_html/dbadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/src/Parser.php(477):
>
> PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Statement->__construct(Object(PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Parser),
> Object(PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\TokensList))
>
> ## 2 /home/dmitrych/public_html/dbadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/src/Parser.php(353):
>
> PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Parser->parse()
>
> ## 3 /home/dmitrych/public_html/dbadmin/libraries/Tracker.php(631): PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Parser->__construct('SET
>
> SQL_MODE=""...')
>
> ## 4 /home/dmitrych/public_html/dbadmin/libraries/Tracker.php(781): PMA\libraries\Tracker::parseQuery('SET SQL_MODE=""...')
>
> ## 5 /home/dmitrych/public_html/dbadmin/libraries/Dat in **/home/dmitrych/public_html/dbadmin/vendor/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/src/Statement.php**
>
> on line **386**

I am expecting a successful export in SQL format.

The actual result is an SQL file with just the error above.

Comment: Something's fundamentally not right with your phpMyAdmin install.

Comment: I've reinstalled phpMyAdmin from the all-languages file, and it's working. Thanks.